# PHP - adding to multi dimensional array adds new arrays to the first array element rather than the correct element

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a 'parent' array that I'm reading and based on some values I read in a child array of that parent I create a new child array. i.e. I sum the number of 'products' in the child array to create a new child array.
The new child array is being created correctly BUT rather than create the new child array in the corresponding parent array element, my logic is placing all of the new child arrays in the first element of the parent. Please help.

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    
   $orderResource = new OrderResource(Order::findOrFail($order['id']));         
   $ordersAll[] = $orderResource;
   
   foreach (($orderResource['products']) as $product) {
    if (array_key_exists($product['productType'],$product_array)) {
        // array_push($product_array, $product['productType']);
        $product_array[$product['productType']] += (int)$product['quantity'];
    }
    else $product_array[$product['productType']] = (int)$product['quantity']; 
    }
    
    $ordersAll['product'][]= $product_array;
    $product_array=[];

}
```

Result: rather than a new 'product' array being in each array element they're all in index 0.

```
    array:22 [▼
  0 => array:9 [▶]
  "product" => array:21 [▶]
  1 => array:9 [▶]
  2 => array:9 [▶]
  3 => array:9 [▶]
  4 => array:9 [▶]
  5 => array:9 [▶]
  6 => array:9 [▶]
  7 => array:9 [▶]
  8 => array:9 [▶]
  9 => array:9 [▶]
  10 => array:9 [▶]
  11 => array:9 [▶]
  12 => array:9 [▶]
  13 => array:9 [▶]
  14 => array:9 [▶]
  15 => array:9 [▶]
  16 => array:9 [▶]
  17 => array:9 [▶]
  18 => array:9 [▶]
  19 => array:9 [▶]
  20 => array:9 [▶]
]
```

So, what I'd like is to have each array index to contain a new 'product_sum' array. This will contain key values for all the Product types found and a sum of the 'quantity'.

current:

```
0 => array:9 [▼
    "refId" => "8e24cc331a73002b0c2da4bc7a62c647"
    "Currency" => "USD"
    "Symbol" => "$"
    "Amount" => "315.50"
    "created_at" => "2020-12-08T03:32:09.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2020-12-08T03:32:09.000000Z"
    "legs" => array:2 [▶]
    "travellers" => array:3 [▶]
    "products" => array:3 [▼
      0 => array:13 [▶]
      1 => array:13 [▶]
      2 => array:13 [▶]
    ]
  ]
```

what I'm after is (in each parent array index):

```
0 => array:9 [▼
"refId" => "8e24cc331a73002b0c2da4bc7a62c647"
"Currency" => "USD"
"Symbol" => "$"
"Amount" => "315.50"
"created_at" => "2020-12-08T03:32:09.000000Z"
"updated_at" => "2020-12-08T03:32:09.000000Z"
"legs" => array:2 [▶]
"travellers" => array:3 [▶]
"products" => array:3 [▼
  0 => array:13 [▶]
  1 => array:13 [▶]
  2 => array:13 [▶]
"product_sum" => array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
   "ticket" => 5
   "bag" => 1
```

Comment: what are you dumping there in that output? also why `$ordersAll['product'][]= $product_array;`?

Comment: If you want a new product array in each array element (of $ordersAll) then you probably need to do `$product['product'][] = $product_array` since $product is the individual element of array within the foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

This line is forcing all the product arrays into the element named `product` of `$ordersAll`:

```
$ordersAll['product'][]= $product_array;
```

Not sure why you are interacting with a Resource this way but you can just reorder this to remove the problem with knowing the current index for `$ordersAll`:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    
    $orderResource = new OrderResource(Order::findOrFail($order['id']));         

    $product_array = [];

    foreach ($orderResource['products'] as $product) {
        if (array_key_exists($product['productType'], $product_array)) {
            $product_array[$product['productType']] += (int)$product['quantity'];
        } else {
            $product_array[$product['productType']] = (int)$product['quantity']; 
        }
    }
    
    // TODO:
    // need the code to add $product_array to $orderResource
    $ordersAll[] = $orderResource;
}
```

Though you should be able to build this list from a couple Collection methods and no need of looping anything yourself:

```
Order::findOrFail(...)->products->groupBy('productType')->map->sum('quantity');
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll see what I can find on solving it with Collection methods. In the meantime, I used your solution, and although it gives me the arrays - Product type: 'quantity' it doesn't return them inside the parent array. My goal is to have this new array inside of each parent Order.

Comment: as what field of the parent? as `OrderResource` is not an array

Comment: Each Order has a few attributes plus 3 arrays (legs, travellers, products) . Ideally I'd like to add the new array under the existing  'products' array.

Comment: how? products is a collection of models i would assume which is going through its own resource to be transformed?  otherwise not sure why a resource is being used at all

Comment: I assumed Resource was needed to obtain the models associated to Order (legs, products, travelers).

Comment: no, they are relationships on the model, resources are for transforming data for output ...add an example to your question of how you want the actual output to look because it would look odd to have a whole collection of models then a random array at the end

Comment: @Justin basically this added data should be an extra field of order, a new field as `products` should only be the collection of products, unless you want to customize that collection and have it hold an extra key for this data then it also holds the 'items' of the collection ... this all really depends upon the output you are trying to build

Answer (score 1):

I beleive this is the issue

```
$ordersAll[] = $orderResource;
    ...
$ordersAll['product'][]= $product_array;
```

You are adding the order to the ordersAll array, but then adding and overwriting the same product key each time.